# Certain BuddyPress Member Profile Data Getting Hyperlinked

Tags: buddypress

Very odd behavior in BuddyPress. When we enter various pieces of information in the About Me textbox on the members profile data in BP, some content is getting hyperlinked as `../members/?s=my content`

Has anyone seen that? How can I correct it or shut off the hyper-linking?

Thanks.

Comment: any BuddyPress gurus out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`// 2012-07-11 -- turns off hyperlinking of content on Members Profile
remove_filter( 'bp_get_the_profile_field_value', 'xprofile_filter_link_profile_data', 9, 2 );`